# Can I insert a browser test or conditional comments in a CSS file?

Tags: css, testing, browser, conditional-comments

Hi
I have a CSS that applies different styles according to the browser, and I want to test for the browser (if browser is not IE) in the CSS file itself (not in the HTML or PHP file).

How can I do it? Should I use this:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<style>
//code
</style>
<![end if]-->
```

in the CSS file???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These conditional comments are IE-only. So checking for `!IE` won't do anything to other browsers ;)

You could inject the CSS with Javascript. I'm just improvising, something like this might do (jQuery):

```
if( !$.browser.msie ) {
  $("#someLinkElement").attr( "href", "webkit.css" );
}
```

Edit: the condition holds for non-IE browsers now

Comment: I actually have a position that I want to apply in all the available browsers,except IE, so... do I need to test all those browsers here int this condition.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to add each browser specific code in a separate file and import required file using the same conditions as you are using and yes, the conditions will be outside of the CSS and inside the actual HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn’t an equivalent syntax to conditional comments that you can use within CSS. Conditional comments are a Microsoft extension to HTML, not CSS.

You could, however, write your CSS file in PHP, and get PHP to serve it as a CSS file.

Note that your conditional comment syntax for detecting browsers that aren’t Internet Explorer is wrong. You want the following:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<style>
//code
</style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

That’ll hide the code between the comments from IE.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to apply specific classes to the `<html>` element of your page based on the browser type/version. You can then target specific browsers from within your CSS file.

This is exactly what the [html5 boilerplate project](http://html5boilerplate.com/) does:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> 
<html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Now to write CSS specifically for IE6 you can just add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.ie6 .some-div {
    margin: 0;
}
```

and so on and so forth.